# Why is malloc not assigning the proper length to my buffer in C?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to assign the buffer a size of THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE which I get from the option arguments on the command line using `buffer = (int*) malloc(THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE);` located at the bottom of the code below.

Here is my code:

```
int* buffer;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int c;
  char *root_dir = default_root;
  int port = 10000;

  // Variable holders created for below
  int n_threads;
  int THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE;
    
  while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "d:p:t:b:")) != -1)
    switch (c) {
    case 'd':
      root_dir = optarg;
      fprintf(stderr, "Root: %s\n", root_dir);
      break;
    case 'p':
      port = atoi(optarg);
      fprintf(stderr, "Port: %d\n", port);
      break;
    case 't':
      // NUMBER OF CONSUMER THREADS
      n_threads = atoi(optarg);
      fprintf(stderr, "Threads: %d\n", n_threads);
      break;
    case 'b':
      // BUFFER SIZE
      THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE = atoi(optarg);
      fprintf(stderr, "Thread Buffer Size: %d\n", THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE);
      break;
    default:
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: wserver [-d basedir] [-p port] [-t threads] [-b buffer]\n");

      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", root_dir);
      fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", port);
      fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", n_threads);
      fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE);

      exit(1);
    }

  // SHARED BUFFER
  buffer = (int*) malloc(THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE);

  fprintf(stderr, "actual buffer size: %d\n", sizeof(buffer));
}
```

When I execute this with `./wserver -d . -p 8080 -t 8 -b 10` I get the following output:

```
Root: .
Port: 8080
Threads: 8
Thread Buffer Size: 10
actual buffer size: 8
```

The actual buffer size should be 10.

When I execute this with `./wserver -d . -p 8080 -t 10 -b 4` I get the following output:

```
Root: .
Port: 8080
Threads: 10
Thread Buffer Size: 4
actual buffer size: 8
```

The actual buffer size should be 4.

Why is it that my actual buffer size is 8 and not the same as my THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE?

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` That's the same as `sizeof(int*)`. It is not the size of the allocated buffer that the variable points to, and it could not be since the pointer does not know the size of that allocation.

Comment: @dxiv is the malloc correctly allocating the space then?

Comment: If [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) returns a non-NULL pointer then it means it succeeded.

Comment: @dxiv yes that helps.

Comment: _Side note:_ Is `THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE` a byte length or an element count? Your `malloc` assumes byte length. If the value is a count, you may want: `buffer = malloc(sizeof(*buffer) * THREAD_BUFFER_SIZE);`

Comment: You don't have to know the actual allocated size by `malloc`. If the value of the pointer returned by `malloc` isn't NULL, you can assume that `malloc` has allocated at least the size specified in its argument.

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of the _pointer_ to your buffer [which is 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine]. It's _not_ how much space is _allocated_ for the buffer. It's an illusion because you did: `-b 4`. Try: `-b 37` and the value will _still_ be 8.